# Sheet declaration goes wrong

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have been using vba for a while and i noticed an annoying bug.
When i use more than 1 sheets in a macro if i set the worksheets everything works just fine until i get an error. After that the worksheet names are messed up and usually uses both declaration for as one sheet.

```
Dim loc_path, sp_path As String
Dim loc_wb As Workbook
Dim sp_wb As Workbook
Dim loc_ws As Worksheet
Dim sp_ws As Worksheet


loc_path = "path1"
sp_path = "path2"
Set sp_wb = Workbooks.Open(sp_path, ReadOnly:=False)
Set sp_ws = sp_wb.Sheets(1)
Set loc_wb = Workbooks.Open(loc_path, ReadOnly:=False)
Set loc_ws = loc_wb.Sheets(1)
```

After that i just call another macro and pass the worksheet or sheets. In an example i pass only the sp_ws to the macro and display the first cells value in a msgbox. Before error it works fine, but after an error if i run it again it will display the loc_ws sheets first cells value.

Is there anything wrong with my code or it is just a bug in VBA?

Comment: When an error happens, the objects are reset. You need to re-initialize the worksheets and other relevant objects

Comment: `Dim loc_path, sp_path As String` only declares sp_path as a string, loc_path will implicitly be a `Variant`. To declare both as a string you need to use `Dim loc_path As String, sp_path As String`

Comment: I tried declaring the string separately, it still doesnt work.
How do i re-initialize the worksheets? i thought if i restart the whole macro it should do that

Comment: I would set the worksheet variables using the sheets' names like so: `Set loc_ws = loc_wb.Sheets("Name of the worksheet")`. If some operation that changes the order of the worksheets takes place, it could cause problems.

Comment: Usually i set it with the name, but in this case these are imported sheets from SAP and both workbooks has only 1 sheet and it could be different name depending on the language settings.